# Is it possible to use factory method with builder pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, factory, builder, factory-pattern, creation-pattern

I'm having this question because:

I know that builder pattern (as far as I understand) should be used when you have to create complex objects (their constructors are large) and factory is for having a class who is responsible for instantiating objects so you can have low coupling and high cohesion

But, since builder and factory are creational patterns I don't know if using both of them make sense or correct.

thanks in advance.

Comment: A builder *is* a factory. Or do you mean creating the builder using a factory instead of a constructor? That only would be sensible.

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have in mind?

Comment: @Bergi yeah, that's what I was thinking, having a method in my factory responsible for creating the builder, then, the builder being responsible for creating my complex object (with large constructors). I don't have code right now, I apologize for that, but I'll post it as soon as possible.

Comment: @TeddyS.: You might as well drop the "factory object" and just start with the builder right away. It's pure, right?